# Why Wait.until() doesn't work in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I have been using Selenium WebDriver. I want to wait until the element is present on the webpage, for which i am using:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Long.parseLong(timeout));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
```

but my test get stucks in the second line if the element I am looking for, is not present and even beyond the timeout. Pls Help. Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, `visibilityOfElementLocated()` looks for "given element if it is visible and has non-zero size". The visibility is based on the style attribute. How long is your timeout? How long did you wait? What do you get if you try just `WebElement ele = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator));`?

Comment: I got it worked. I changed the timeout from 60000 to 60 since it takes the second argument as seconds and not millisecs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked. I changed the timeout from 60000 to 60 since it takes the second argument as seconds and not millisecs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:
- the element *is* present, so no exception is thrown
- then gets stuck because you are not doing anything else afterwards

Try printing smt after the `until` call. My guess is it will get printed.

Otherwise maybe it's the timeout:
It must be in seconds, not milli seconds.

[http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#WebDriverWait(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#WebDriverWait%28org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver), long)

Comment: Snap!.. I was writing the answer while you were writing that you solved  :) Anyway, good.